# Solving a summation using summation rules

Tags: summation

I am given two problems.

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} (4i + \frac{3}{4}n + \frac{1}{2}) \tag 1$$

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} (4i + \frac{3}{4}n + \frac{1}{2}) \tag 2$$

I am asked to solve it.

I know I can manipulate this into three separate summations:

Attempt:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n} (4i) + \sum_{i=0}^{n} (\frac{3}{4}n) + \sum_{i=0}^{n} (\frac{1}{2}) \tag 1  $$

Unfortunately, I am confused on how to proceed other than the fact that the third summation will turn into $\ \frac{1}{2}$. (because there is no i or n)

May anyone share with me the next step? I'm not sure in what form the solution should be in.

EDIT:

would the first term turn into: $\ 4 \times \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

EDIT 2:

I've currently got

$$ \left(4 \times \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right) + (?) + \frac{1}{2}n \tag 2$$

Comment: @nickD the starting point of the lower limit is different

Comment: Yes to the last prompt.  The second and third terms are independent of $i$.

Comment: Note that the summation is over $i$ and the summands of the second and third summation do not depend on $i$. N.B. The third sum will *NOT* turn into $\frac{1}{2}$: it is a sum of $n$ of them.

Comment: ... or $n+1$ of them, depending on the lower limit (which I missed - sorry).

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{i=1}^n 1 = n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the OP has parenthesized things correctly in the question, it should go like this:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^{n} \left(4i + \frac{3}{4}n + \frac{1}{2}\right)
& = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \left(4i \right) + \sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{3}{4}n + \sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{1}{2} \\
&= 4 \sum_{i=0}^{n} i + \frac{3}{4}n\sum_{i=0}^{n} 1 + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n} 1\\
& = 4 \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + \frac{3}{4}n(n+1)+ \frac{1}{2}(n+1) \\ 
& = 2n (n + 1) + \frac{3}{4}n(n+1)+ \frac{1}{2}(n+1)\\
& = \frac{11}{4} n(n+1) + \frac{1}{2} (n+1)
\end{align*}